# in Oracle JDBC is it possible to batch stored procedure calls and retrieve OUT parameters?

Tags: java, stored-procedures, jdbc, oracle11g, batch-processing

I have a stored procedure in an Oracle 11g database like f(a IN, b IN, c OUT).
I want to call it from JDBC in batch mode and then read all the OUT variables.
Is this possible? 
I have this so far

```
  CallableStatement statement = connection.prepareCall("f(?, ?, ?)");
  for(Item i : items) {
     int i = 0;
     statement.setString(++i, item.getA());
     statement.setString(++i, item.getB());
     statement.registerOutParameter(++i, Types.NUMERIC);
     statement.addBatch();
  }
  statement.executeBatch();
  int[] answers =  ?
```

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sadly, no.

> The ability to make batch updates is the same for CallableStatement
>   objects as it is for PreparedStatement objects. In fact, a
>   CallableStatement object is restricted to the same functionality that
>   a PreparedStatement object has. More precisely, when using the batch
>   update facility, a CallableStatement object can call only stored
>   procedures that take input parameters or no parameters at all.

Reference: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/jdbc/getstart/callablestatement.html#1000220

Comment: I have a procedure with a body like 'update ttest f set  f.dt = sysdate where 1=1' called 600 times. It takes about 30 seconds. Calling update query directly with a PreparedStatement, near the same time. Using a batch reduced time in the case of PreparedStatement to nearly 1 second, but had no effect with procedure.