# Stored Procedure OUT parameter value extraction required for BatchSqlUpdate

Tags: java, spring, oracle, batch-processing

I am successfully using BatchSqlUpdate implementation for doing batch stored procedure (Oracle Function) calls. The call is successful and I get the results updated on the back-end.

The only problem is how to successfully parse the return and OUT argument values. 
The following way is how I have implemented this,

```
public class MyClass extends BatchSqlUpdate {

    private StoredProcedureAttributes spAttributes;
    private final Map<String, Object> inParameters;
    List<Map<String, Object>> batchedOutArguments;

....

    public MyClass (StoredProcedureAttributes spAttributes, int batchSizeRequired) 
            throws SQLException {

        // Call statement will look like
        // { :SP_OUT_RETURN_VALUE = call myschema.MY_FUNC(:p_error_message,:p_module_context_name,:p_sql_error,:p_host_id,:p_code,:p_value_type,:p_value)}
        super (spAttributes.getDataSource(), spAttributes.getCallStatement());

        this.spAttributes = spAttributes;
        declareParameters();
        setBatchSize(batchSizeRequired);        
        compile();

.....


    private void declareParameters() {

        for (StoredProcedureParameter spParameter : this.spAttributes.getStoredProcedureParameters()) {

            switch (spParameter.getArgumentType()) {
                case IN: 
                    declareParameter(new SqlParameter(spParameter.getParameterName(), spParameter.getSqlType()));
                    break;
                case OUT:
                    declareParameter(new SqlOutParameter(spParameter.getParameterName(), spParameter.getSqlType()));
                    break;
                case IN_OUT: 
                    declareParameter(new SqlInOutParameter(spParameter.getParameterName(), spParameter.getSqlType()));
                    break;
            }
        }

        LOGGER.debug("Declared parameters for [{}]", STORED_PROC_NAME);
    }

.....

    public int execute(EntityWriterState writerState) throws StoredProcedureException {

        int rtnVal = 0;

        for (StoredProcedureParameter spParameter : this.spAttributes.getStoredProcedureParameters()) {

            switch (spParameter.getArgumentType()) {
                case IN: 
                case IN_OUT: break;
                case OUT:
                    Object outParam = null;
                    inParameters.put(spParameter.getParameterName(), outParam);
                    break;
            }
        }

        try {

            super.updateByNamedParam(inParameters);
            batchedOutArguments.add(inParameters);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new StoredProcedureException(ex);
        }
```

Each set of parameters (for making one procedure call) including the OUT parameter references is kept in batchedOutArguments.

But no luck in getting any thing for the OUT type variables,
On Oracle side my procedure looks like,

```
create or replace FUNCTION           "MY_FUNC" (
      p_error_message         OUT NOCOPY VARCHAR2,
      p_module_context_name   OUT NOCOPY VARCHAR2,
      p_sql_error             OUT NOCOPY VARCHAR2,
      p_host_id             IN VARCHAR2,
      p_code                 IN VARCHAR2,                               
      p_value_type           IN VARCHAR2, 
      p_value                IN NUMBER)
    RETURN NUMBER
  AS
....
```

Any ways to get the OUT variables extracted?

Comment: What happens if you get rid of `NOCOPY` on the output parameters?

Comment: No change -- It's (batchedOutArguments.get(outVariableNames)) still null.  I even tried assigning a non-null value for the OUT arguments before calling the procedure, and post procedure call the value is still same.

Comment: I think I found the the answer here ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10858816/in-oracle-jdbc-is-it-possible-to-batch-stored-procedure-calls-and-retrieve-out-p?rq=1

Comment: Trying to log the procedure error before leaving the procedure, and would read from the error table.... So, will add a generic exception catch to log the message before leaving the procedure. I think that is the only way out to pass the value back as the procedure called transaction can feed the value back.